# Server-side copy failed when moving file via dbutils

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I'm new to Databricks and working my way through a book on it, doing samples and all that but I've hit an error I cant seem to resolve, I'm trying to move a file from the driver to the dbfs using the command (this is azure databricks)

```
dbutils.fs.mv("file:/tmp/seasons.csv", "dbfs:/tmp/seasons.csv")
```

and I get the following back when it runs

> "java.io.IOException: Server-side copy has failed. Please try disabling it through `databricks.spark.dbutils.fs.cp.server-side.enabled`"

I've done some digging but cant seem to find a solution, any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Comment: Can you please come up with a more generic title? Yours is too specific /s also you shouldn't add tags to the title, that's what tags are for.

Comment: I updated the title for him so when a mod comes in to verify it, this should fix that @cafce25

Comment: So .. do some tests? you are trying to go from file to dbfs .. .can you do file to file and dbfs to dbfs or does that error as well ..

Comment: Just a small doubt - where are you running this move command ? directly in a notebook or through databricks-connect or something else ?

Comment: Hi, I'm runing directly from notebook. As for copying if I dbutils.cp then I can copy it from file to file with no isues. If I try and use cp rather than mv I get the same error.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug in Runtime 13.3 + . Downgrade to 13.2 (if possible)

Comment: Solved the problem for me, no changes in code were done, just downgrading the runtime did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Set the spark conf
`spark.conf.set("databricks.spark.dbutils.fs.cp.server-side.enabled", "false")` if you face this issue. I wouldn't recommend downgrading to 13.2 since 13.3 is LTS.

(This would be a comment, but I lack reputation).
When you scroll down to the error cause, what does it say?